# Layout não aparece no "_layout.cshtml"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout

Estou editando o arquivo _layout.cshtml para que ele possa ser replicado nas demais páginas.

Porém, quando rodo meu programa é como se eu não estivesse feito nenhuma alteração no layout.

O que pode ser?

À propósito estou tendo o erro parecido com esse:

> The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context", este erro me impede de ver meu layout? de testa-lo?

Meu Layout está feio e sem nenhuma modificação!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>PROJECT</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Scripts.Url("~/scripts/jquery-extensions.js")" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Scripts.Url("~/scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" />
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="body_principal">
        <div>
            <div id="cabecalho">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/fundo_cabecalho.png")" width="200" height="100"/></a>
                <div id="vision">
                <div id="logo">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/logo_header.png")" width="337" height="92" /></a>
                <div id="status">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr><img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/fundo_status_01.png")" width="99" height="34" /></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.Action("Switch", "Vision")
                </div>
                    <div id="user">
                        @User.Data.Name
                    </div>
                <div id="icones">
                        <img alt="@User.Data.Name" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/16/ico_user.gif")" align="middle" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

     </header>
    <div id="conteudo">
                <div id="conteudo-principal">
                    <div id="barra-lateral">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/pixel.gif")" height="1" width="1" />
                        <div id="menu_lateral">
                            @Html.Action("Menu", "Vision")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="principal">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/pixel.gif")" height="1" width="1" />
                        <div id="titulo">
                            @this.ViewBag.Title @(this.ViewBag.SubTitle == null ? string.Empty : " / ")
                            <span id="subtitulo">@this.ViewBag.SubTitle</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div id="content">@this.RenderBody()</div>
                        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="console"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Scripts.Url("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: SS]

[image: SS]

Comment: Nas suas Views você está referenciando o Layout?  `@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} `

Comment: Já, não é isso!

Comment: Você pode colocar o código do layout na sua pergunta?

Comment: coloquei acima.

Comment: Qual a linha que o compilador aponta o erro?

Comment: Postei a imagem acima

Comment: Esse projeto parece estar inteiro desconfigurado. Como estão os References do projeto?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está o erro:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Scripts.Url("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" ></script>
```

Não existe `@Scripts.Url`. Provavelmente você tentou usar intuitivamente.

Use simplesmente:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Outra coisa que é preciso conferir é se as bibliotecas dinâmicas estão registradas no Razor. Verifique dentro do arquivo `web.config` **dentro do diretório `Views`** (atenção aqui porque existem dois arquivos `web.config` dentro do projeto) se há uma seção de configuração com o seguinte:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: deixei como vc sugeriu, continua dando erro.. á propósito eu estou com os erros assim:  "The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context", este erro me impede de ver meu layout? como posso corrigir? as bibliotecas estão sendo utilizadas corretamente

Comment: @ThamiresCunha É problema de configuração do seu projeto. Estou editando.

Comment: Morrison Postei outra imagem.. veja essas configurações já estão lá. É mesmo um desafio descobrir a causa desses erros..